# regarding cross browser css

Tags: css

many people write css but they don't have good command for writing cross browser css which will display same output in various browser. it is not possible to test a site on different browser with different different version. so i need to know is there any library available or not for those people who may not write cross browser css.  the library will generate right & cross browser css after detecting browser just like Modernizr which will generate everything perfect for old browser which does not have support for html5 & css3.

i am finding easy way to generate cross browser css without giving much effort and knowledge.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) but even then it will not be 100% compatible with all web browsers.